# How to bind to UITextView.EditingDidBegin in MvvmCross (Xamarin Studio)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

If there isn't already a binding for this - can somebody show me how to add a new binding for this (and register it)?

I've tried locating the UIButton.TouchUpInside binding handler code so I could copy that... without luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom bindings are demonstrated and discussed in full in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n28-custom-bindings-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html

Further, the 'built-in' custom bindings are all in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target

---

However, since `EditingDidBegin` is a standard `EventHandler` delegate (not a custom `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`) then there's no need for a custom binding - instead the standard binding should work:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
set.Bind(textField).For("EditingDidBegin").To(vm => vm.MyEditingBeginCommand);
set.Apply();
```

Comment: Hi Stuart - thanks for the help. Unfortunately, neither my current binding `this.AddBindings (new Dictionary<object, string>(){
    {this.textField, "EditingDidBegin MyEditingBeginCommand; Text TextFieldValue"},` nor your suggested binding work. Should I go the route of creating a custom binding?

Comment: Woops - sorry I had used an incorrect variable name. It does in deed work - I thought it was odd that it didnt..